# compiler problems with variable template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

The following code (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14)) defines the [variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) `pi<>`:

```
template<typename T=double>
constexpr T pi = T(3.14159265358979323846264338328);
template<>
constexpr const char* pi<const char*> = "π";
```

With the clang compiler (Apple clang version 12.0.0) (with C++14), this triggers a **warning** (with `-Weverything`):

> no previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'pi<const char *>'
>
> declare 'static' if the variable is not intended to be used outside of this translation unit

Moreover, since this was defined in a header, multiple instances of 'myNameSpace::pi<char const*>' were created, causing **linker errors**.

So, as suggested, I added the `static` keyword, which silenced the warning:

```
template<>
static constexpr const char* pi<const char*> = "π";
```

But now gcc (9.3.0) is unhappy, giving an **error** pointing at the `static` keyword:

> error: explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class

What is the correct way to avoid either warning and error?

Comment: Can't reproduce the warning on the Clang 11 (non-apple).

Comment: What compiler settings are you using?  I can't reproduce the warning [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4E6E6z)

Comment: It's `clang`s `-Wmissing-variable-declarations`  I suspect gcc is correct and would silence that warning from `clang` using `-Wno-missing-variable-declarations`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for that.  Now I can confirm.  OP, are you stuck with C++14?  In C++17 you can use `template<typename T=double>
constexpr inline T pi = T(3.14159265358979323846264338328);
template<>
constexpr inline const char* pi<const char*> = "π";` which removes the warning.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, `-Weverything`. See edited post, also note the linker error

Comment: I think getting around the linker error will require either the C++17 "inline variable" feature or some sort of implementation layer using an underlying function template or class template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning from (this old version of) Clang is partly **misleading**, but does indicate the **real** problem that you eventually encountered with the linker.  The warning describes the good rule of thumb that a global variable ought to

1. appear with `extern` in a header and then without in a source file, or
2. appear with `static` in a source file (avoiding collisions with any other symbol).

The latter choice doesn't apply to explicit specializations: since linkage applies to templates as a **whole** (the standard says that it pertains to the *name* of the template, which is evocative even if it doesn't work well for overloaded functions), you can't make just one specialization `static` and Clang is **incorrect** to accept it.  (MSVC also incorrectly accepts this.)  The only way to make a "file-local specialization" is to use a template argument that is a local type, template, or object.  You can of course make the whole variable template have internal linkage with `static` or an unnamed namespace.

However, the former choice does apply: an explicit specialization is not a template, so it must be defined exactly **once** (in a source file).  Like any other global variable, you use `extern` to reduce the definition to a declaration:

```
// pi.hh (excerpt)
template<typename T=double>
constexpr T pi = T(3.14159265358979323846264338328);
template<>
extern constexpr const char* pi<const char*>;

// pi.cc
#include"pi.hh"
template<>
constexpr const char* pi<const char*> = "π";
```

(Since the primary template is, well, a template, it *is* defined in the header file.)

As mentioned in the comments, C++17 allows inline variables; your explicit specialization again behaves like an ordinary global variable and can be defined with `inline` in a header if desired.

Comment: Thanks, good answer!. However it implies that the example on Wikipedia is wrong or at least misleading

Comment: @Walter: You’re welcome.  Aside from concerns of brevity and the same rules applying to (non-inline) function template specializations, the example isn’t *wrong* for a source file—and who says it’s not an excerpt from within an unnamed namespace?

Comment: No, it's not wrong, but certainly misleading. I expect better from Wikipedia.